# What matrix implements forward differences in regression

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, linear-algebra

I have an equation Yit = XitB

The question asks to consider a transformation of data y and X whereby forward differences are calculated so Yit becomes Yit - 1/(T-t)Σ s=1 yi(t+s) so basically it's self minus the mean of future observations. And the same for Xit. Image below

[image: formula for forward difference]

Derive matrix A so that pre-multiplication of y and X by the Kroneker product of Identity (N) and A implements this transformation. I don't quite know where to start working out what matrix A looks like - maybe uppertriangular of ones?

Thanks!

Comment: You can read the elements of $A$  from this formula - just put it in a matrix multiplication form

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a pointer on how to start that?